# Add thousands seperator with total price in WooCommerce product pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add total price in single product page. Unfortunately I'm not a programmer. It means I actually don't know about JavaScript or code well.

So I searched some codes on google and added it in `function.php` file.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 29 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('price total','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>'.'KRW');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html(product_total.toFixed(0));

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

My problem is the code doesn't show thousands separator. How can I do that?

And I want to add the total price between quantity and add to cart button. Now the total price is before quantity.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript It will help you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Although it doesn't work, thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I have tested this code and it works perfectly, now.

Explanations. There is 2 parts in your code:

1. Displaying initial product price with php. I have use here php function **`number_format()`** to format price with a thousand coma separator.
2. Updating total price by the quantity using jQuery. I am using javascript **`replace()`** function with a custom **[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)** in it.

So here is your working code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 25 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $product_price = number_format($product->get_price());


    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('price total','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product_price.'</span>'.' KRW');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
                        var product_total_formated = product_total.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1,");

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html(product_total_formated);

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Placing your price in the right location:**

Here it is an extract from **`content-single-product.php`** template that shows the order (placement) of different elements on page, through hooks:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

As you can see, to correct position for your function is between priority **`20`** and **`30`**. So I have chose priority **`25`**.

Reference:

- [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript/14428340#14428340)